# BlazeDS: Converting action script type Class (for an embded image) to Java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, class, blazeds, equivalent

I am using BlazeDS for my flex3 application and I need to transfer an embedded image from actionscript to java. Any hint on how to do that? To what java class does actionScript's Class type correspond?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In one of my projects I have done this by serializing the image (PNG) to a byte array and transferring the array, and then reconstruct it.